# Windows data types

Tags: c++, reference

I need help with a very small problem

here goes the piece of code

```
       WCHAR a[10]={'a','b','c'};
       LPWSTR b =a;
       scanf("%S",&a);
       LPWSTR c =a;


line 1   a="abc" 
line 2  b="abc"
line 3   a="hello"
line 4  c="hello" ; b="hello"
```

whenever i change the value of `a` , value of `b` also changes ..
that is reference of `a` is only stored in `b`

what should i do so that value of b does not change ...

I know my question is simple but i am a beginner to windows data types

can anyone help me overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   LPWSTR b =a;
```

This sets `b` to the same value as `a`, so now `b` points to the same place `a` does, the array you created in the first line. If you want to copy the values of an array, use some kind of copying function.

You should use real string classes rather than pointers.

Comment: iam new to this data type , so could you give me an example ??

Comment: @user3781814 An example of what? `LPWSTR` is a pointer to a wide string.

Comment: string classes or copying function ??
will strcpy work for this ?

Comment: You would probably want a [wide character or multi-byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk6xf663.aspx) version. But really, don't do this. Use proper C++ types for your strings and interface with `LPWSTR` only when you have to. There's no reason to manipulate inside a `LPWSTR` and lots of reasons not to.

Comment: okay!! can you give me the piece of code so that i get distinct values for 'b' and 'c' ??

Comment: @user3781814 `std::wstring b, c;`. To get a `LPWSTR`, use `c_str`.